# How to trigger click event without simulating it for Realex payments API

Tags: javascript, jquery, realex-payments-api

I built a shopping cart that processes orders through AJAX before calling the Realex payment API. The issue I am having is that occasionally browsers will outright block the lightbox popup because it assumes it's a spam popup because of how it's initiated.

```
new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'processOrder.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
    }).done(function(response){
        resolve(response);
    }).fail(function(){
        reject('Response failed');
    })
}).then((data) => {
    RealexHpp.setHppUrl('https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay');
    RealexHpp.lightbox.init('rhpp', data.return, JSON.parse(data.hpp));
    $('#rhpp').click();
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I've contacted technical support, and I've been told that the issue is specifically the `$('#rhpp').click();` because it's simulating the click rather than being an actual click desired by the user.

So, without actually editing the #rhpp element to ask users to click manually, is there anything I can do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the `init` method for the **Hosted Payment Page (HPP)** lightbox is the ID of the button element that when clicked, will initiate the lightbox.

If you modify the `rxp-js.js`, you can include a new `init` method (or override the existing one) that doesn't register a click event handler on a button but instead initializes the lightbox immediately.

**Example:**

This is the original `init` method of `rxp-js.js` as per version 1.3.1.

```js
init: function (idOfLightboxButton, merchantUrl, serverSdkJson) {
    //Get the lightbox instance (it's a singleton) and set the sdk json
    var lightboxInstance = RxpLightbox.getInstance(serverSdkJson);

    // Sets the event listener on the PAY button. The click will invoke the lightbox method
    if (document.getElementById(idOfLightboxButton).addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById(idOfLightboxButton).addEventListener("click", lightboxInstance.lightbox, true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(idOfLightboxButton).attachEvent('onclick', lightboxInstance.lightbox);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", internal.receiveMessage(lightboxInstance, merchantUrl), false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('message', internal.receiveMessage(lightboxInstance, merchantUrl));
    }
},
```

This is my modified version of the `init` method.

```js
init: function (merchantUrl, serverSdkJson) {
    //Get the lightbox instance (it's a singleton) and set the sdk json
    var lightboxInstance = RxpLightbox.getInstance(serverSdkJson);

    lightboxInstance.lightbox();
}
```

Note the changes I have made:

1. Removed the first parameter named `idOfLightboxButton`, and related code that adds the click event handler to the button.
2. Removed the second parameter named `merchantUrl`, and related code that adds a message event handler (I handle the response from the merchant in my own way).
3. Added a called to the `lightbox()` method on the `lightboxInstance` object. This is what opens the lightbox.

If you were to take this approach, you would then just update your promise callback to read like.

```js
...
.then((data) => {
    RealexHpp.setHppUrl('https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay');
    RealexHpp.lightbox.init(JSON.parse(data.hpp));
})
...
```

Of course, if you were keeping the `merchantUrl` parameter then the above would read a little differently.

Comment: Hmm, the code seems to work perfectly fine on most browsers, but Firefox mobile is failing to open the popup, it just duplicates the currently open tab.

Comment: @Chaosxmk, I have found that when using the Hosted Payment Page lightbox, it's best to force the library to use the modal popup on the current page as opposed to a full page redirect. This is achieved, again, by modifying `rxp-js.js` to not discriminate between screen sizes and always use the modal popup. See the `isMobileNewTab` check [here](https://github.com/globalpayments/rxp-js/blob/9909985b96ab5ed945614affad5f3739827f956b/dist/rxp-js.js#L553).